# Is there an elegant way to rename Java boolean values to improve the readability of my code?

Tags: java, boolean, readability

Say I have the following (Java 8) code:

```
private void toggleNewUser() {
    if (ToggleButton.isOn()) {
        fadeLabel(true);
        transitionButtons(true);
    }
    else {
        fadeLabels(false);
        transitionButtons(true);
    }
}
```

My `fadeLabel` and `transitionButtons` functions switch between fading and transitioning in and out, and they do so when the boolean are `true` and `false` respectively. But I would like to replace `true` and `false` with "in" and "out" to improve the readability of my code. Is there any elegant way to do so?

The only way I could come up with is kind of clunky and not really elegant:

```
private void toggleNewUser() {

    boolean in = ToggleButton.isOn();
    boolean out = ToggleButton.isOn();

    if (ToggleButton.isOn()) {
        fadeLabel(in);
        transitionButtons(in);
    }
    else {
        fadeLabels(out);
        transitionButtons(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use an enum

Comment: Or just a `static final boolean`.  But I don't think renaming `true` and `false` this way would improve readability.  (Using an `enum` would actually be better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a simple way, maybe defining constants for TRUE and FALSE is fine? Define them in your class like:

```
public static final boolean IN = true;
public static final boolean OUT = false;
```

Otherwise you're pretty limited with Java. You could also try enum:

```
public enum Anim {
    IN(true),
    OUT(false);
     
    public final boolean state;
     
    private Element(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first suggestion is already better than what I came up with, and you also taught me something new about enums. I will accept your answer if nothing better comes along. Thank you!

Comment: Excuse the lack of semicolon; people here on stack quickly edited it. I'm using Kotlin and forgot bout them :)